# Autocmd pattern to match empty file/no filename

Tags: autocmd

Say I want to match a buffer with no filename.

I can use the pattern `*`, then manually check the filename, like `autocmd myVimrc BufEnter * if @% == "" | echom 'blank filename' | endif`

Is there a pattern to match just blank filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` seems to work for just blank filenames.

Example: `autocmd myVimrc BufEnter {} echom 'blank filename'`. Much cleaner